# Creating a .NET StreamWriter object from classic ASP - constructor parameter problem

Tags: .net, asp-classic, interop, vbscript

I'm trying to create and use a .NET StreamWriter object inside a classic ASP page (VBScript).  Normally I would create the object like this:

```
Dim writer
Set writer = Server.CreateObject("System.IO.StreamWriter")
```

However, the constructor for StreamWriter takes a Stream object as a parameter, and the call to CreateObject fails. Even if I could get a parameterless constructor to execute without error, the BaseStream property of the StreamWriter class is read-only, so I couldn't set it to my Stream after object creation.

Is there a way to specify constructor parameters when doing interop from VBScript to .NET in this way?  And no, doing this doesn't work:

```
Set writer = Server.CreateObject("System.IO.StreamWriter", stream)
```

My alternative would be to create my own .NET wrapper class with a paramterless constructor and register that assembly for COM interop, but I'd like to avoid that if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/9a83b51e-7ff1-448b-9585-fb8353a5ee43), and [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/iissdk/html/3ca5f82f-8e96-44ed-bbea-fc62cc01e457.asp), it is not supported. You need to create a wrapper class in .NET in order to use the StreamWriter from classic ASP.

Comment: you linked same page twice =)

Comment: The documentation link does not have any content.